# How do i implement Paypal in Laravel with PayPalCheckoutSdk

Tags: laravel, curl, guzzle

If i'm start from here, what i'm suppossed to do? To get to the paypal overlay in Frontend? (With some prefilled values sth. like this https://websolutionstuff.com/adminTheme/assets/img/pay.png) that's all i want for now.

```
    $environment = new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
    $client = new PayPalHttpClient($environment);

    $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
    $request->prefer('return=representation');
    $request->body = [
        "intent" => "CAPTURE",
        "purchase_units" => [[
            "reference_id" => "test_ref_id1",
            "amount" => [
                "value" => "100.00",
                "currency_code" => "USD",
            ],
        ]],
        "application_context" => [
            "cancel_url" => "https://example.com/cancel",
            "return_url" => "https://example.com/return",
        ],
    ];

    try {
        $response = $client->execute($request);
        print_r($response);
    } catch (HttpException $ex) {
        echo $ex->statusCode;
        print_r($ex->getMessage());
    }
```

}

Comment: https://websolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-laravel
know that this solution is deprecated, but can someone please show the line which invoke this window? https://websolutionstuff.com/adminTheme/assets/img/pay.png

Comment: welcome to so, I would suggest to use backend for paypal payments for security purposes as you have used guzzle tag so I guess you want to use it, then call paypal requests using guzzle and logs

Comment: Can you show me the line of code which starts the paypal overlay? I'm stuck at this point,  or is there a redirect to Blade, which implements the JSPaypal library? Honestly this is part that drives me nuts, i tried smrklive, paypalsdk and without any library, but i don't see the line of code which forces the paypal payment to appear? Where this https://websolutionstuff.com/adminTheme/assets/img/pay.png window is coming from? Maybe that is my question in a nutshell.

Comment: if you use paypal api services you would get api create the frontend accordingly, then send request to paypal via guzzle in backend, the picture you are showing is the frontend, is the issue in frontend or in backend code

Comment: the main issue is the poor paypal documentation and that it seems there are hundreds ways to implement what i want and none of them is properly documentated. My problem is, that i'm stuck in the backend, in literal way, i call route->controller->function in controller->than i've no idea how  and where to redirect, what comes from paypal and what comes from a blade i've created etc.

Comment: Is this approach possible? I use the ClientJSClientSDK api which seems hassle free, and after payment, paypal.com sends something to may laravelsite backiend? with this data i'll update my database? Seems more complicated first, but i only have to deal with something coming from Paypal in the backend and the complicated part is done by paypal default frontend implementation.  Is this possible?

Comment: bhucho thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If stumple over this question, and you are more a JS Frontend than a backend guy like me, maybe it's best to use the

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/javascript-sdk/

for frontend and get your data to backend via

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/IPNIntro/

For laravel there is no no-brainer implemtation like

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing

for paypal.

There are tons of packages out there, there are tons of solutions, but in early 2021 there is none of them simple or done in a few hours, if don't need paypal, and use laravel, go for Cashier(Stripe) and save a lot of time.

If you are backend/PHP guy maybe this is not a solution for you, and you will see it as a dirty/difficult workaround.